# Should I set up my website with Amazon EC2 or S3? And how I connect it to a database?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have 6 months of coding experience and I'm trying to get my first website on air. It's a one-page website at the end of which I ask for the user's email, for registration purposes. I only used HTML/CSS/JavaScript to make it and PHP to make the database connection. I've already bought my domain name and I'm using MySQL.

Should I host it with Amazon EC2 or Amazon S3? And how can I associate an Amazon RDS database to my website?

I've gone through a lot of tutorials, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks!!!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Software/hosting recommendations are explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using PHP, you can't use S3, so it will need to be EC2 if you want to go the AWS route. S3 can only host static files - i.e. html, images, css and javascript - things that don't run on the server. PHP runs on the server.

To be a bit clearer: You can use S3 along with EC2 (i.e. storing some of your files there), but you can't run a PHP based website off of S3.

Answer (score 1):

Using a RDS is quite simple.

You just have to think that it's a MySQL Server. You can connect to it using :

```
mysql -h your.rds.dns -u root -p
```

From a Server authorized on the RDS' security group (recommanded to be private and only accessible from your web server).

You can also import your current database using a dump :

```
mysql -h your.rds.dns -u root -p database < myMySQLdump
```

The second step is to add the  RDS DNS entry to all your php files that point to your current MySQL Server, which is quite often "localhost" with your database credentials.

Doing it that way you will seperate the Web Server from your Database Server, increasing your performances.

Answer (score 1):

If there’s very minimal usage of the php stack, I’d say stick to S3 and have the html call a function on lambda which could do any SQL for u, avoids managing the EC2, but idk if you are saving much money tbh